Interview bit TLE on singular inputs
I am doing interview bit now, and the code i write works fine, except that for test cases of singular elements,it almost always gives tle.
for example, the question
Given two strings A and B, find the minimum number of steps required to convert A to B. (each operation is counted as 1 step.)

You have the following 3 operations permitted on a word:

Insert a character
Delete a character
Replace a character


Input Format:

The first argument of input contains a string, A.
The second argument of input contains a string, B.
Output Format:

Return an integer, representing the minimum number of steps required.
Constraints:

1 <= length(A), length(B) <= 450
Examples:

Input 1:
    A = "abad"
    B = "abac"

Output 1:
    1

Explanation 1:
    Operation 1: Replace d with c.

Input 2:
    A = "Anshuman"
    B = "Antihuman"

Output 2:
    2

Explanation 2:
    => Operation 1: Replace s with t.
    => Operation 2: Insert i.

https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/edit-distance/
gives tle on test case
A : "b"
B : "a"
where expected answer is 1.
My code for the same is
int isinsert;

int ans(int la, int lb, string a, string b, int i, int j){
    if(i==la-1&&j==lb-1){
        if(a[i]==b[j]){
            return 0;
        }
        return 1;
    }
    int sol=0;
    if(i==la||j==lb){
        return 1e9;
    }
    if(isinsert == 0){
        sol=min(ans(la, lb, a, b, i+1, j), ans(la, lb, a, b, i+1, j+1));
        if(a[i]!=b[j]){
            sol+=1;
        }
    }
    if(isinsert == 1){
        sol=min(ans(la, lb, a, b, i, j+1), ans(la, lb, a, b, i+1, j+1));
        if(a[i]!=b[j]){
            sol+=1;
        }
    }
    if(isinsert == -1){
        sol=ans(la, lb, a, b, i+1, j+1);
        if(a[i]!=b[j]){
            sol+=1;
        }
    }
    return sol;
}

int Solution::minDistance(string A, string B) {
    if(A==B){
        return 0;
    }
    int la=A.length();
    int lb=B.length();
    if(la==lb && la==1){
        return 1;
    }
    if(la>lb){
        isinsert=0;
    }
    if(la<lb){
        isinsert=1;
    }
    if(la==lb){
        isinsert=-1;
    }
    return ans(la, lb, A, B, 0, 0);
}

seeing how i have
if(la==lb && la==1){
    return 1;
}

I don't think I should get tle.
Any help is appreciated
thanks.
edit: i haven't implemented dp vector yet but that shouldn't be the problem, as far as i know
An answer of someone else that worked is:
int min(int x, int y, int z) { return min(min(x, y), z); }

int Solution::minDistance(string A, string B) {
    int m=A.size(),n=B.size();
    vector<vector<int>> dp(m+1, vector<int>(n+1, 0));
    for(int i=0;i<=m;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<=n;j++){
            if(i==0) dp[i][j]=j;
            else if(j==0) dp[i][j]=i;
            else if(A[i-1]==B[j-1]) dp[i][j]=dp[i-1][j-1];
            else dp[i][j]=1+min(dp[i-1][j],dp[i-1][j-1],dp[i][j-1]);
        }
    }
    return dp[m][n];
}

I don't know the reason why. pls help.

Have you stepped through your code using a debugger to see where it's getting hung up?

I have used multiple cout statements to find that only the
if(la==lb && la==1){
return 1;
}
is being executed for the given test case. Is it something with interview bit as i cant find anything about its tle or checking policies. The answer is correct and although i havemt used memoisation, i should not get tle as that part is never executed. I have asked chagpt for it and exhausted its procedures of debugging the problem.

Try using a debugger.  You have a failing test case and this should be trivial to create a [mcve] for where you can debug locally.

The answer is correct. It is that why that seems to take longer on interview bit than the proposed answer.

And a debugger can tell you why it's taking longer.  So will a profiler.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

debugger time says it does not take long, as expected.
